# RPC Cookie error in gwtp-sample-basic-spring example

Tags: java, spring, gwt, cookies, rpc

I cloned [this example](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-basic-spring)

When running it, I get the following error

> An error occured: Cookie provided by RPC doesn't match request cookie, 
>       aborting action, possible XSRF attack. (Maybe you forgot to set the
>       security cookie?) While executing action:
>          com.gwtplatform.samples.basicspring.shared.dispatch.SendTextToServerAction

How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question to fix typos and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after 3 days of googling i found a solution.

Overide isSecured method in SendTextToServerAction calss:

```
public class SendTextToServerAction extends ActionImpl<SendTextToServerResult> {
    private String textToServer;

    public SendTextToServerAction(final String textToServer) {
        this.textToServer = textToServer;
    }
    /**
     * For serialization only.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private SendTextToServerAction() {
    }

    public String getTextToServer() {
        return textToServer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecured() {
        return false;
    }
```